# python write doesn't work

Tags: python, io

For some reasons, I cannot write anything to a blank text file. I used file.close() in the end, but it still doesn't work at all. So could anyone point out where I might get wrong?

Below is the full code, and basically what I am doing is to retrieve unique email addresses from a text file, and then match these unique emails with unique five digits numbers, and finally write to a new file replacing emails by these numbers.

```
import re
import random


email_list = []
anon = {}
number_list = []

##There are 54 unique emails, so I set len(number_list) = 54 here
while len(number_list) < 54:
    rand = random.randint(10000,99999)
    rand = '%%' + str(rand) + '%%'
    if rand not in number_list:
        number_list.append(rand)

i = 0

a = open('mbox.txt','r')
for line in a:
    if re.findall(r'[A-Za-z\.-]+\S@[\w\.-]+\.[\w]+',line):
        email = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z\.-]+\S@[\w\.-]+\.[\w]+',line)[0]
        if email not in email_list:
            email_list.append(email)
            anon[email] = number_list[i]
            i += 1
    else:
            email = "NA"


b = open('mbox-anon.txt','wt', encoding='utf-8')

for line in a:
    for email in anon:
        try:
            linereplace = line.replace(email,anon[email])
            b.write(linereplace)
        except:
            pass
a.close()
b.close()
```

Comment: Hold on you iterate over `b`, a file with `wt` permissions. In that case the file has no lines...

Comment: Using `except: pass` can hide your errors from you.  Try `except e: print e`

Comment: Take in account that if you read and write to the same file in a loop you might end with undesired effects (if you write at the end of the file in the same loop that reads the file you might end in an infinite loop)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry that was a typo, it should be  'a'

Comment: the first loop already reads all lines in a. when you execute the second loop no lines will be left to read. do a `a.seek(0)` as suggested by Uriel Eli. However you might consider using the first loop over a to write to b.

Comment: @Will I changed to except e: print e.  But it still does nothing, I did not get any error, and nothing appears in the file

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Thank you. Could you please elaborate on 'consider using the first loop over a to write to b'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your intention was to replace the first file contents and put them into the second file, you should replace `for line in b` with

```
a.seek(0)
for line in a:
```

---

Or open `b` before the first loop, and add

```
b.write(line.replace(email, anon[email]))
```

for every iteration.

Comment: OP says that the text file is blank, though. Maybe it's okay to open `mbox-anon.txt` in write-only mode, and OP should instead be iterating over data read from `mbox.txt`?

Comment: @Tagc it wasn't really clear, but i believe your interpretation is more likely

Comment: But he already does a `for line in a` just a little bit above. Why not putting the writing to b inside that loop then?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to replace the first file contents and put them into the second file

Comment: @UrielEli After I try a.seek(0), write works. But in file b, the contents are all repeated 53 times, and it does not replace emails by numbers. Instead, they are all emails like this: Received: from holes.mr.itd.umich.edu (holes.mr.itd.umich.edu [141.211.14.79])
Received: from holes.mr.itd.umich.edu (holes.mr.itd.umich.edu [141.211.14.79])
Received: from holes.mr.itd.umich.edu (holes.mr.itd.umich.edu [141.211.14.79])
Received: from holes.mr.itd.umich.edu (holes.mr.itd.umich.edu [141.211.14.79])
Received: from holes.mr.itd.umich.edu (holes.mr.itd.umich.edu [141.211.14.79])

Comment: @Parker all of these addresses are not valid emails, so your regex cant recognize these.

Comment: And you might consider `anon[email] = str(number_list[i])`, otherwise it is an integer and things get messy.

Comment: @UrielEli I think the emails are valid. Now the problem is that I was getting same output in multiple lines. I believe the problem comes from the for loop.

Comment: @UrielEli Also, can you please say more about 'add b.write(line.replace(email, anon[email])) before first loop'. I am not sure how this works with the two for loops

Comment: I meant you can open the second file where you open the first, and write to the second while iterating the first, without the need in two for loops.

Comment: @UrielEli I see what you are saying. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think this code does what you're after. It reads a file `mbox.txt`, extracts all emails from it and maps each unique email address to a 5-digit value following your approach. It then writes the same data to `mbox-anon.txt`, substituting each email address for its corresponding 5-digit value.

```
import random
import re


def generate_crypto_value():
    return '%%{}%%'.format(random.randint(10000, 99999))


def obscure_emails(file_in, file_out, email_masker):
    with open(file_in) as f_in, open(file_out, 'w') as f_out:
        data = f_in.read()

        email_pattern = r'[A-Za-z\.-]+\S@[\w\.-]+\.[\w]+'
        for email in set(re.findall(email_pattern, data)):
            data = data.replace(email, email_masker())

        f_out.write(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obscure_emails(
        file_in='mbox.txt',
        file_out='mbox-anon.txt',
        email_masker=generate_crypto_value)
```

**Example `mbox.txt` before run**

```
Here's one address: foo.bar@email.com
Another address: baz@hotmail.org
And the first address again: foo.bar@email.com with some text after it
```

**Example `mbox-anon.txt` after run**

```
Here's one address: %%61286%%
Another address: %%51955%%
And the first address again: %%61286%% with some text after it
```

Comment: thank you! But do you think it's possible to just edit the last part of my code?

Comment: There are enough issues in your code that it's easier to just start from scratch. For instance, it's much better practice to manipulate files using a context manager, as this will automatically close file handles even if an exception is thrown (among other benefits).

Comment: Thanks very much! I will look at those